# Control TV out widescreen iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotifications

Hi I am making an app that uses external screen to mirror the app. Is there a NSNOtification for detecting if the phone is widescreen mode?

Comment: Hi @objectiveCarlo, did you have any answer to this?